# How to restrict domain axis labels in HistogramDataSet

Tags: jfreechart

I am using following code to display the HistogramDataSet

```
double[] v1 = {0.5,.7,.8,1.5,1.7, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 2.0,2.2,3};
HistogramDataset dataset = new HistogramDataset();
dataset.addSeries("1",v1, 3,.5,3);
```

it creates 3 bins but it keep the (start and end boundary of indivisual bin) i.e. range of each bin itself,but i want to put the range of each bin myself ,i.e. the first bin should be from 0.5 to 1.0 and the second bin should be from 1.0 to 2.0 and the third bin from 2.0 to 3.0..
How i will do it...plz help me

Answer (score 1):

There are two histogram dataset implementations in JFreeChart, I would recommend you use the other one, [SimpleHistogramDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/SimpleHistogramDataset.html), because it works more along the lines you are expecting.